# clicking element identified by XPath returns an error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, click

I used to use the following syntax in chrome console to click on an element for testing

```
$x('somexpath expression').click()
```

but now when trying to execute this code I get an error

> VM234:1 Uncaught TypeError: $x(...).click is not a function

This may be due to some update of Chrome.. Can one guide me which syntax should now work to click on an element identified by XPath in Chrome Console

Comment: Most likely the XPath expression doesn't actually match anything. What do you see if you just do `$x('somexpath expression')`?

Comment: this works in console: `$x('somexpath expression')[0].click()` just tried in the console on this very page `$x('/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[4]/a[1]')[0].click()` it opens up the "Load 7 more related questions" link

Comment: My element is unique. I have checked.
Can I ask which version of chrome do you use? mine is Version 116.0.5845.180 (Offizieller Build) (32-Bit)